# Displaying a list in form of an upside down pyramid graphic

Tags: list-manipulation, graphics

I was wondering how to display a list like this:

```
list={{0,1,1,0},{1,0,1},{1,1},{0}}
```

in form of an upside down pyramid, that is the first element of the list is on top, the last on the bottom. I used MatrixForm and this seems to work, but I wanted it more to look like a graphic which I can color for example.

So my question is: How can I create a pyramid graphic and "place" the number pyramid in it?

Comment: Try with `Column[Row[#, " "] & /@ list, Center]` and `Graphics Inset Polygon` etc.

Comment: @Kuba I think that's the easiest answer. Wanna post?

Comment: @belisarius the question is also about formatting, coloring etc. And I don't have time now :) feel free to incorporate that :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use Grid, and transform your list in a matrix with empty strings where you do not want something to be shown, for example as follows:

```
list = {{0, 1, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 1}, {1, 1}, {0}};
n = Length[list];
Grid[ Table[ With[{i = n - Length[d]}, 
   RotateLeft[PadLeft[Riffle[d, ""], 2 n + 1, ""], i]], {d, list}]]
```

(*

```
    0       1       1       0
        1       0       1   
            1       1       
                0
```

*)

Grid has a lot of options for spacing, colouring etc.