# Display a list or array as a centred triangle

Tags: list-manipulation, display

How can I get Mma to display an array like 
{{2, 1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0}} 
as an upside down triangle where the first row is the base and the last row is the tip, with each row centred something like (although the centering here is not perfect):

[image]

In this specific examples my array has lots of 0's but in general this will not be the case.

Moreover, the general array would contain $n$ rows, with row 1 containing $n$ elements, row 2 containing $n-1$ elements etc. and I would like to display this as a triangle where each row is centred w/r to the first row, generalizing the figure above.

[For context these arrays are [Gelfand-Tsetlin patterns](http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/combinat/sage/combinat/gelfand_tsetlin_patterns.html).]

Comment: possible duplicate: [Displaying a list in form of an upside down pyramid graphic](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/66458/125)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
arr = {{2, 1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0}};

With[
 {r = Riffle[#, ""] & /@ arr},
 {l = Max[Length /@ r]},
 Grid[CenterArray[#, l, ""] & /@ r]
]
```

[image]

`CenterArray` is new in 11.0, but it should be easy to implement in earlier versions.

Comment: So simple when you ask an expert.  Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

```
centered = Column[Row[#, Spacer @ 5] & /@ #, Alignment -> Center] & @ #;

centered @ arr
```

[image]

```
centered @ {{1111, 2, 3333, 4}, {a, bbbb, c}, {9, 8}}
```

[image]

or, perhaps, for cases like the second example, wrap each entry with `Pane` with appropriate `ImageSize` option value:

```
centered2 = Column[Row[Pane[#, {80, Automatic}, Alignment -> {Center, Center}] & /@ #,
        Spacer[5]] & /@ #, Alignment -> Center] &;

centered2 @ {{1111, 2, 3333, 4}, {a, bbbb, c}, {9, 8}}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

For those not using version 11, this works on 10.1, though it's a bit messier:

```
triangleDisplay[l_] := Module[{pl, rl},
    pl = Table[{i, i + 2 j - 1}, {i, 1, Length[l]}, {j, 1, Length[l[[i]]]}];
    rl = Flatten[Table[Rule[pl[[i, j]], l[[i, j]]], {i, 1, Length[l]}, {j, 1, Length[l[[i]]]}], 2];
    Grid[Normal[SparseArray[rl, {Length[l], 2 Max[Length /@ l] + 1}, Null]]]
];
```

Comment: @ZeroTheHero: There's a scroll bar beneath it, and it should copy fine. kglr's answer is cleaner though, unless you want to make sure that none of the elements overlap.

Comment: Hmmm... I can scroll but do not see a scrollbar.  Well: it works and that what matter.  Thanks!

Comment: It's an iPad thing... the scrollbar clearly appears on the laptop.  I really like your solution as a module.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a variation of @Szabolcs' solution that allows elements to overlap:

```
Options[triangleGrid] = Options[Grid];

triangleGrid[a_List, opts:OptionsPattern[]] := With[{len = 2 Length[a[[1]]]},
    Grid[
        CenterArray[
            Riffle[#, SpanFromLeft, {2, 2 Length[#], 2}],
            len,
            ""
        ]& /@ a,
        opts
    ]
]
```

For your example:

```
triangleGrid[{{2,1,0,0}, {1,0,0}, {0,0}, {0}}]
```

[image]

When the widths of the elements are not the same:

```
triangleGrid[{{1111,2,3333,4}, {a,bbbb,c}, {9,8}}]
```

[image]

Note how `3333` and `bbbb` overlap. Also, in the above, the individual columns are all sized differently. You can make them the same with:

```
triangleGrid[{{1111,2,3333,4}, {a,bbbb,c}, {9,8}}, ItemSize->1]
```

[image]